# Multidimensional Array - How to access it in volt

Tags: multidimensional-array, phalcon, volt

ok i created a multidimensional array and stored it in articles

if i do

```
{{ dump(articles) }}
```

It returns

```
array(2) {
  ["Comedy"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "Comedy Title1"
    [1]=>
    string(57) "Comedy Title2"
    [2]=>
    string(41) "Comedy Title3"
  }
  ["Horror"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "Horror Title1"
    [1]=>
    string(57) "Horror Title2"
    [2]=>
    string(41) "Horror Title3"
  }
}
```

Now what i am trying to achieve is to loop through, print the heading and then the title for each section so:

```
**Comedy**
Comedy Title1
Comedy Title2
Comedy Title3

**Horror**
Horror Title1
Horror Title2
Horror Title3
```

However i can access the titles no problem but cannot seem to access the heading.

Heres what i have so far

```
{% for heading in articles %}
    {{ heading[loop.index0] }}
{% endfor %}
```

This returns the first value from the 1st section and the 2nd value from the 2nd section

```
 comedy Title1
 horror Title2
```

if i do

```
{% for heading in articles %}
    {% for title in heading %}
        {{ title }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This returns all the titles in the correct order but without the header so:

```
Comedy Title1
Comedy Title2
Comedy Title3
Horror Title1
Horror Title2
Horror Title3
```

So thats perfect but i just need to print out the headers at the start of each array and thats what i cant figure out

I would have thought it was stored in the heading section but {{ heading }} returns an array and {{ heading[0] }} returns the first title. {{ articles }} returns an array and {{ articles[0] }} and even {{ articles[0][0] }} returns nothing

I know how to do this in regular php however i cant figure it out for volt, no doubt something simple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Volt, but based on doc's try touse something like:

```
 {% for key, heading in articles %}
   ** {{ key }} **<br />
        {% for title in heading %}
            {{ title }}<br />
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

[docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html)

Comment: doh! yeah forgot its actually the key not the value i'm accessing. Works a charm